# Can someone explain the simplification of this boolean algebra equation?

Tags: boolean, algebra, simplification

> I think I missed reading a theorem or postulate or something..
>
> The equation is: wy + wxz + xyz
>
> According to my professor, the simplification is (which she didn't explain how):
> wy + xz(w'y + wy')
> = wy + xz (w XOR y)
>
> Where did that (w'y + wy') came from??
>
> I tried to calculate it but so far I only got: (w+x)(w+y)(w+z)(x+y)(y+z)

Comment: Not sure why your teacher chose to go the xor route. I think you can go directly from `wy + wxz + xyz` to `wy + xz(w + y)`.

Comment: can I convert that (w + y) to (w + w'y)?

Comment: Write out the truth tables to find out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about basic algebra and not programming as defined in the [help] pages.

Answer (score 0):

In a Boolean expression `+` is `XOR` and `*` is `AND`. This is the same as identifying `true` with `1` and `false` with `0`, with the only special convention that `1 + 1 = 0` (or `2 = 0` if you wish.)

With these definitions both `+` and `*` are *commutative*, i.e., `a + b = b + a` and `a * b = b * a`. In addition, the distributive law is also valid `a * (b + c) = a * b + a * c`. Note also that the `*` operator is usually implicit in the sense that we write `ab` instead of `a * b`.

Applying these properties to the expression `wy + wxz + xyz`, there are some few obvious transformations you can do:

1. `wy + wxz + yxz` (commute `x` with `y`)
2. `wy + (w + y)xz` (prev plus distribute `xz`)
3. `wy + xz(w + y)` (prev plus commute `(w + y)` with `xz`

Note that the last one is `wy + xz(w XOR y)` because `+` is nothing but `XOR`.

**ADDENDUM**

Regarding the expression of your professor, let's recall that `a' = 1 - a` by definition. So

```
w'y + wy' = (1 - w)y + w(1 - y) - def
          = y - wy + w - wy     - distribute
          = y + w               - simplify (a + a = 0 always)
          = w + y               - commute
```

which shows that s/he was right.